# I am printing list of Latin letters of ogonek in c using unicode

Tags: c, unicode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{   int i;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"de_DE.UTF-8");
    wchar_t cA[256] = { 
        0xC498, 0xC4AE, 0xC5B2, 0xC482,   0xC496, 0xC48E, 0xC898, 0xC89A, 0xC48A, 0xC4A0,   0xC4B9, 0xC5BB, 0xC7B8,   0xC485,   0xC499,   0xCAF,
       0xC5B3, 0xC483, 0xC497, 0xC48F,   0xC899, 0xC89B, 0xC48B, 0xC587, 0xC49A, 0xC4A1,   0xC4BA, 0xC5BC, 0x20,     0x21,     0x22,     0x23,
       0xC582,  0x25,  0x26,   0x27,     0x28,   0x29,   0x2A,   0x2B,   0x2C,   0x2D,     0x2E,   0x2F,   0x30,     0x31,     0x32,     0x33,
       0x34,    0x35,  0x36,   0x37,     0x38,   0x39,   0x3A,   0x3B,   0x3C,   0X3D,     0x3E,   0x3F,   0x40,     0x41,     0x42,     0x43,
       0x44,    0x45,  0x46,   0x47,     0x48,   0x49,   0x4A,   0x4B,   0x4C,   0x4D,     0x4E,   0x4F,   0x50,     0x51,     0x52,     0x53,
       0x54,    0x55,  0x56,   0x57,     0x58,   0x59,   0x5A,   0x5B,   0xE1B5BE, 0x5D,   0xC581,  0x5F,  0xC484,   0x61,     0x62,     0x63,
       0x64,    0x65,  0x66,   0x67,     0x68,   0x69,   0x6A,   0x6B,   0x6C,     0x6D,    0x6E,    0x6F,  0x70,     0x71,     0x72,     0x73,
       0x74,    0x75,  0x76,   0x77,     0x78,   0x79,   0x7A,   0xC2AB,  0xC5AF, 0xC2BB,  0x013D,  0XC4A6,0xC3A1, 0xC3A0, 0xC3A9, 0xC3A8,   0xC3AD, 0xC3AC, 0xC3B3, 0xC3B2, 0xC3BA, 0xC3B9,   0xC391, 0xC387, 0xC59E,   0xC39F,   0xC2A1,   0xC5B8,
       0xC3A2, 0xC3A4, 0xC3AA, 0xC3AB,   0xC3AE, 0xC3AF, 0xC3B4, 0xC3B6, 0xC3BB, 0xC3BC,   0xC3B1, 0xC3A7, 0xC59F,   0xC49F,   0xC4B1,   0xC3BF,
       0xC4B6, 0xC585, 0xC2A9, 0xC4A2, 0xC49E, 0xC49B, 0xC588, 0xC591,  0xC590, 0xE282AC, 0xC2A3,   0x24, 0xC480,    0xC492,   0xC4AB,   0XC5AA,
       0xC4B7, 0xC2B9, 0xC4BB, 0xC4A3,   0xC4BC, 0xC4B0, 0xC584, 0xC5B1, 0xC5B0, 0xC2BF,   0xC4BE, 0xC2B0, 0xC481,   0xC493,   0xC4AB,   0xC5AB,
       0xC381, 0xC380, 0xC389, 0xC388,   0xC38D, 0xC38C, 0xC393, 0xC392, 0xC39A, 0xC399,   0xC598, 0xC48C, 0xC5A0,   0xC5BD,   0xC390,   0xC4BF,
       0xC382, 0xC384, 0xC38A, 0xC38B,   0xC38E, 0xC38F, 0xC394, 0xC396, 0xC39B, 0xC39C,   0xC599, 0xC48D, 0xC5A1,   0xC5BE,   0xC491,   0xC580,
       0xC383, 0xC385, 0xC386, 0xC592,   0xC5B7, 0xC39D, 0xC395, 0xC398, 0xC39E, 0xC58A,   0xC594, 0xC486, 0xC59A,   0xC5B9,   0xC5A6,   0xC3B0,
       0xC3A3, 0xC3A5, 0xC3A6, 0xC593,   0xC5B5, 0xC3BD, 0xC3B5, 0xC3B8, 0xC3BE, 0xC58B,   0xC595, 0xC487, 0xC59B,   0xC5BA,   0xC5A7,    0xC4A7,
        };
        for( i=0;i<252;i++){
            wprintf(L"%lc\n", (unsigned char)cA[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried by writing setlocale, but even though it is showing different symbols.I need it to print the correct symbols. Eg. for 0xC498 it is printing ÿ instead of Ę.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum. Please [edit] your question when adding new information, like reactions to our comments asking for clarification. -- Are you aware that the actual representation of the output depends on the application you use to view it? What operating system do you use? Which application shows the output, for example a shell (Windows speak: command line)? Did you try to redirect the output into a file and view this with an editor capable of displaying Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the function wprintf, you are typecasting the `wchar_t`
   (equivalent to `uint16_t`) to `unsigned char` (equivalent to
   `uint8_t`). Hence, you are losing half of the information every time
   you are printing something.
2. I think you have an incorrect set of uni-code for the Latin characters. Please follow the chart https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode and try again.
3. Meanwhile, `wprintf(L"%lc\n", (wchar_t)0x0118);` will give you the character you are looking for.